# security in serving private content s3 + cloudfront + signed URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I've read aws docs about using s3 + cloudfront + signed URL architecture to securely serve private content to public users. However it seems not secure enough to me. Let's me describe in steps:

Step 1: user logs in to my website.

Step 2: user clicks download (pdf, images, etc.)

Step 3: my web server will generate signed URL (expiry time: 30 secs), redirect user to the signed url and the downloading process happens.

Step 4: now, even though it's timed out after 30 secs, there is still a chance that any malicious snipper on my network will be able to catch the signed url and download my user's private content.

Any thought for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The risks you anticipate exist no matter what mechanism you use to "secure" anything on the web, if you aren't *also* using HTTPS to encrypt your users' interactions with the web site.

Without encryption, the login information, or perhaps cookies conveying the user's authentication state are also being sent in cleartext, and anything the user downloads can be directly captured without need for the signed link... making concern about capturing a download link via sniffing seem somewhat uninteresting compared to the more significant risk of general and overall insecurity that exists in such a setup.

On the other hand, if your site is using SSL, then when you deliver the signed URL to the user, there's a reasonable expectation that it will be hidden from snooping by the encryption... and, similarly, if the link to S3 also uses HTTPS, the SSL on that new connection is established *before* the browser transmits any information over the wire that would be discoverable by sniffing.

So, although it seems correct that there are potential security issues involved with this mechanism, I would suggest that a valid overall approach to security for user interactions should reduce the implications of any S3 signed URL-specific concerns down to a level comparable to any other mechanism allowing a browser to request a resource based on possession of a set of credentials.

Comment: In fact I should've indicated that all communication is through HTTPS. Now the concern is just whoever gets the signed URL, regardless of the expiry time, will potentially be able to download my private file. Chance is slim, however it is possible. I examined the Dropbox's approach, actually they still serve through their webservers, not directly through signed URL. So another security layer is added.

Comment: That's true, possession of the url means access to the content, as could possession of the browser cookies or the user's password.  Streaming the file through your web server, while arguably inefficient, is not as bad as some would make it out to be, since AWS does not charge for the bandwidth between S3 and EC2 within the same region (so the transfer toward your server is effectively "free") and streaming a file from network to network uses a resource (network) that is less scarce than downloading the file from a more conventional web server (disk).  The key concept is stream, not fetch/send.